# Recreate Mail.app Search Index?

Tags: macos, apple-mail, spotlight

It seems that the search index for my Mail.app has been corrupted. I have 4 years of emails, but when searching via the built-in search in Mail.app it always returns no results. Anyone have any idea how the search index can be rebuilt or recreated in Mail.app on OS X?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Prior to Lion Mail keeps its database at `~/Library/Mail/Envelope Index`. For Lion it's `~/Library/Mail/V2/MailData/Envelope Index`.

It's a sqlite database. To regenerate the entire file simply quit mail then delete the file. Mail will create a new one at next launch (it may take a while depending on the size of your mailboxes).

Caveate: I've only done this prior to Lion. I see in my `MailData` directory there are several files on Lion I'm not familiar with, so it may behave differently. You're responsible for backing up your own data before nuking anything.

Comment: Right, but this is the actual Mail database, correct? As in, all the emails and so and so forth. I wouldn't want to delete that, just the search index.

I guess I could open the sqlite database and trawl through it hoping to find a search table that I could clear, but that would be uber-risky in the extreme...

Comment: No it's not all the email messages themselves. Those will all be in a directories named after your account. E.g., `IMAP-username@imap.gmail.com`.

Comment: Worked a treat. Thanks. Sorry about the confusion, I had read a very similar solution on another site that would have had me delete the entire inbox.

Answer (score 1):

If the `~/Library/Mail/Envelope Index` trick does not work, which it did not for me there are a number of other steps one can take to rebuild the mail search index, some outlined here: http://www.chriswrites.com/2012/02/find-missing-emails-in-mac-os-xs-mail-app/

1. try `mdimport -r /System/Library/Spotlight/Mail.mdimporter` in the Terminal
2. try `sudo mdutil – E` in the Terminal (admin password required), or via the Spotlight preferences, add the whole computer to the 'Privacy' list of excluded folders, then remove it; both actions will force a recalculation of the spotlight index
3. in my case, all the above failed to do anything, and I got an error message when trying to change the Spotlight privacy settings, indicating my whole index was really messed up. The solution was to type the following in the Terminal:

   `sudo mv /.Spotlight-V100 /Spotlight-V100-old`

   and then restart the computer, to force a reindex of the machine. You can also then clean up the folder "Spotlight-V100-old" that will now appear on your hard drive.

   This third nuclear option also requires admin privileges.

Comment: this `sudo mv /.Spotlight-V100 /Spotlight-V100-old` help me a lot. thanks.